# Django extends template issue

Tags: html, django

Okay so I have my index.html file which has a file called info.html which exntends from the index.html file but it isn't quite working currently. Here's my code:

index.html

```
<body>

    {% include "home/quote.html" %}

    {% include "home/intro.html" %}

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% include "home/projects.html" %}

    {% include "home/goals.html" %}

</body>
```

info.html

```
{% extends "home/index.html" %}

{% block content %}

<section class="info-section">

    <div class="info-section_content">

        {% include "home/includes/info-content.html" %}

    </div>

</section>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Isn't working how? And how are you rendering this?

Answer (score 1):

Essy Fix!

In views.py in the apps directory i was rendering the parent file (index.html) so I have now switch to render the child file (info.html) and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

I would need some more information on your project to know for sure, but I would check to make sure that you are referencing the proper namespace here:

```
{% extends "home/index.html" %}
```

For instance if the path is something like templates/home/something/info.html or templates/something/home/info.html this could be the issue.